# IE11 Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf' (but it's not an object and works in other browsers)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser, legacy

I have a script that iterates through values passed in an array and checks whether those items are natively supported by a browser. This works fine in Chrome, Edge, FireFox and Safari, but IE11 and older (the browsers that *really* need this to work) throws an error.
The array values are strings (as can be seen below) but for some reason, IE11 is treating them as objects, which means when I try to check for a . in the string, IE is erroring out.

I have tried converting the array item `toString`, but that just results in `object object` or `object undefined`.

I have setup a CodePen which contains the full set of code:
https://codepen.io/willstocks_tech/pen/YBEzLW?editors=1012

The version that can be used in IE is: https://s.codepen.io/willstocks_tech/debug/YBEzLW/mWAoNxdogGvr (although this might expire!)

```js
//https://github.com/willstocks-tech/dynamically-polyfill-features-for-a-script/releases/
dynamicPolyfill(
 ['IntersectionObserver', 'IntersectionObserverEntry', 'Object.assign', 'Array.copyWithin']
 ,'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/quicklink@1.0.0/dist/quicklink.umd.js' 
 ,'quicklink()' 
)

function dynamicPolyfill(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad) {
 if(typeof Promise !== "undefined"){
  var checkPromises = [];
  if(Array.isArray(tocheck)) {
   tocheck.forEach(
    function(tocheck){
     checkPromises.push(checking(tocheck))
    }
   )
  } else {
   checkPromises.push(checking(tocheck))
  }
  checkPromises = checkPromises.filter(function(p){return p !== undefined}).join(' ');
  loadPolyfill(checkPromises, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad)
 } else {
  promiFill(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad);
 }
}

function promiFill(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad){
  var promPolyfill = document.createElement('script'); 
  promPolyfill.src = ('https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise'); 
  document.body.appendChild(promPolyfill); 
  promPolyfill.onerror = function(response) { 
   console.error("Polyfilling promise failed", response); 
  } 
  promPolyfill.onload = function(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad) {
   dynamicPolyfill(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad);
  }
}

function checking(check){
 var splitChars = '.';
 if ((check in window) != true || (check in this) != true) {
  if (check.indexOf(splitChars) >= 1) {
   var split = check.split('.');
   var firstWord = window[split[0]];
   var lastWord = new Object(split[split.length - 1]);
   if (lastWord in firstWord != true && lastWord in firstWord.prototype != true) {
    return check;
   }
  } else {
   return check;
  }
 }
}

function loadPolyfill(url, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad) {
 if(url !== "") {
  var polyfill = document.createElement('script'); 
  polyfill.src = ('https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features='+encodeURIComponent(url)); 
  document.body.appendChild(polyfill); 
  polyfill.onerror = function(response) { 
   console.error("Loading the polyfill(s) failed!", response); 
  } 
  polyfill.onload = function() {
   loadMyScript(scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad)
  }
 } else {
     loadMyScript(scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad)
 }
}

function loadMyScript(url, functionToRunonLoad) {
 if(Array.isArray(url)) {
  var promises = [];
  url.forEach(
   function(url){
    promises.push(nonblankURL(url));
   }
  );
  Promise.all(promises)
   .then( 
    function() {
     initialiseMyScript(functionToRunonLoad)
    }
  ).catch(function(error){return error})
 } else if (!Array.isArray(url) && url !== null && url !== '') {
  nonblankURL(url)
   .then( 
    function() {
     initialiseMyScript(functionToRunonLoad)
    }
  ).catch(function(error){return error}) 
 } else {
  initialiseMyScript(functionToRunonLoad) 
 }
}

function nonblankURL(uri){
 return new Promise( 
  function(resolve, reject) { 
   var thescript = document.createElement('script');
   thescript.src = encodeURI(uri);
   document.body.appendChild(thescript);
   thescript.onerror = function(response) {
    return reject("Loading the script failed!", response);
   } 
   thescript.onload = function() {
    return resolve(uri);
   } 
  }
 )

}

function initialiseMyScript(functionToRunonLoad) {
 if(Array.isArray(functionToRunonLoad)) {
  functionToRunonLoad.forEach(
   function(functionToRunonLoad){
    initScript(functionToRunonLoad)
   }
  )
 } else { 
  initScript(functionToRunonLoad)
 }
 function initScript(fn) {
  try {
   window[fn];
  } catch(err) {
   console.error('There was an error: ', err, err.name, err.stack);
  }
 }
}
```

All other browsers seem to handle this fine, but IE11 and older throw the following error:
`SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf'`

I can't work out for the life of me how to get this to work in IE, but also in all other browsers at the same time!

Comment: How does it come, that you're trying to use `indexOf` of `null`? I mean, when the condition passes, `check` doesn't exist ...

Comment: The code in your question had a syntax error (I discovered this when putting it in an on-site runnable snippet). I've added what seems to be the appropriate `}`, but please check it against your actual code. It's **always** best to use copy and paste to copy your code (after first getting it down to the absolute minimum [MCVE](/help/mcve)), to avoid introducing errors like that.

Comment: Apologies for the poor code snippet - I have now added the full code snippet - the error is not at Promise, but is at `if (check.indexOf(splitChars) >= 1) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see in the IE11 debugger that `tocheck` is an Event object at that point (which obviously doesn't have `indexOf`). That's because of this code:

```
promPolyfill.onload = function(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad) {
    dynamicPolyfill(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad);
}
```

The first and only argument a DOM event handler receives is an event object, but you're accepting it as `tocheck` and then calling `dynamicPolyfill` with that event.

You may have meant:

```
promPolyfill.onload = function() {
    dynamicPolyfill(tocheck, scriptToPolyfill, functionToRunonLoad);
};
```

or similar. In any case, the issue is calling `indexOf` on an `Event` object.

Comment: Ahaaaa - @t-j-crowder thank you! Sorry, I’m still fairly new to JS and was pulling my hair out as I couldn’t work out why it kept thinking it was an object!